Generate path between 2 points to achieve a desired momentum
I have 2 points and I need to find a path between them to maximize momentum.
You can consider this as a trajectory of a Racquet hitting a tennis ball.

In the image above, the momentum in the direction of the blue dotted line would be very less because of the linear path(green line) between the points.

In the image above, the momentum in the direction of the blue dotted line would be high because of the non-linear path(green line) between the points.
Question:

Is there any way to find a path between 2 points to achieve a desired(or maximum) momentum at the end point(second point)?

EDIT:
Spherical Joint Image:


What are the constraints?

@user58697 The generated path has to be followed by the racquet mounted on a spherical arm. Have attached a picture of it in the question. Not much limit on acceleration unless it dose not feel like supernatural.
